# How to show all tables in database dynamically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I want to select all tables in my database

[image]

Using Dynamic-SQL:

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'',
  @base nvarchar(max) = N'select * from $x$;';
SELECT  @sql += REPLACE(@base, N'$x$;', QUOTENAME(name)+';
')
  FROM sys.all_objects where type='U'
--PRINT @sql;
/*
select * from [trace_xe_action_map]; -- Why get this table!
select * from [trace_xe_event_map];  -- and this too!
select * from [errorTable];
select * from [table_objects];
select * from [table_fields];
select * from [alter_table];
select * from [computed_colonnes];
select * from [colonnes];
select * from [nullish_columns];
select * from [test];
*/
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

When I've run this: it tells me error that:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Invalid object name 'trace_xe_action_map'.

besides that I've added in the *clause where condition*  `and (name!='trace_xe_action_map' or  name!='trace_xe_event_map');` but the same error?
How can I skip those two selected values *(trace_xe_action_map, trace_xe_event_map)*?
I also tried `Top 8` with  `order by 1 desc` to avoid two first records, But in the result I just got the first table selected dynamically! Instead of all tables.

Comment: Use `sys.objects` instead of `sys.all_objects`. Better yet, use `sys.tables` with no `WHERE` clause.

Comment: thanks for specification, but just out of curiosity how can I avoid the two rows returned in table?

Comment: Add `and is_ms_shipped = 0`

Comment: What do you mean avoid the two rows?

Comment: @Larnu even though the query returned tables that I don't want how can I don't show them I've used `where clause` it's not worked for me, so I tried `top with order by`

Comment: FYI self referencing variables like that are a [documented Antipattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) use actual string aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved with the help of [dan-guzman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711162/dan-guzman) and [larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu)

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N''
select @sql = String_Agg(Concat('select * from ', QuoteName(name)), '; ' + Char(13)) from sys.tables
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```